# 4th Shooting statement not working in SFML game

Tags: c++, sfml

I am currently creating a game using SFML 2.0. Basically it is a top-down shooter and I am having difficulty with the statement below. Which shoots an arrow when the space bar is pressed. There are four statements which depend on the way the player sprite (archSprite) is facing. This is determined from the source.y which is calculated by this function

```
enum DirectionKeys { Up, Left, Down, Right};

sf::Vector2i source(0, 0);
int getCellY(DirectionKeys direction)
{
    return (direction*64);
}
```

I am following the logic that the statement

```
int dir = source.y/64;
```

Will find out the direction the sprite is facing with the spritesheet I am using 0 = Up 1 = Left 2 = Down 3 = Right This statement shoots correctly for everything except shooting right Can anyone figure out why my arrow for direction right is shooting down and the arrow is not rotating? It is like the statement for shooting right is being ignored all together. Can anyone please advise?

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Tilemap.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>



 if(keypress == sf::Keyboard::Space && keyPressed)
 {
 int tblt = this->_game_data.curr_bullet;
 this->_arr_bullet_data[tblt].active        = true;

 //every 100th bullet it is set to the up rotation 
 int dir = source.y/64;

 if (dir == 0)
 {
    _arr_bullet_spr[tblt].rotate(90);
    this->_arr_bullet_data[tblt].startpos     = this->archSprite.getPosition() + sf::Vector2f(64,-42);
    this->_arr_bullet_data[tblt].direction  = sf::Vector2f(0,-1);
 }
 else if (dir == 1)
 {
    _arr_bullet_spr[tblt].rotate(360);
    this->_arr_bullet_data[tblt].startpos     = this->archSprite.getPosition() + sf::Vector2f(-22,0);
    this->_arr_bullet_data[tblt].direction  = sf::Vector2f(-1,0);
 }
 else if (dir = 2)
 {
    _arr_bullet_spr[tblt].rotate(270);
    this->_arr_bullet_data[tblt].startpos     = this->archSprite.getPosition() + sf::Vector2f(0,96);
    this->_arr_bullet_data[tblt].direction  = sf::Vector2f(0,1);
 }
 else if (dir = 3)
 {
    _arr_bullet_spr[tblt].setRotation(180);
    this->_arr_bullet_data[tblt].startpos = this->archSprite.getPosition() + sf::Vector2f(0,0);
    this->_arr_bullet_data[tblt].direction  = sf::Vector2f(1,0);
 }

 this->_arr_bullet_spr[tblt].setPosition(this>_arr_bullet_data[tblt].startpos);
 this->_game_data.curr_bullet++;
 }
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(dir = 2)` and `if(dir = 3)` must be `if(dir == 2)` and `if(dir == 3)` respectively.

Comment: Wow, such a rookie mistake. Thank you.